# VB.NET AddHandler to each button control while looping through controls

Tags: vb.net, loops, controls, addhandler

I am trying to add mouseenter and mouseleave events to each button while I'm looping through the controls like:

```
For each control in me.controls
       With control
            If TypeName(control) = "Button" Then
                AddHandler control.MouseEnter, AddressOf control.DynamicButton_MouseEnter
                AddHandler control.MouseLeave, AddressOf control.DynamicButton_MouseLeave
            end if
next
```

And it says "MouseEnter is not an event of object". So I wonder how do I reference the dynamic button?

Comment: Cast the control up to the desired control type.

Comment: What do you mean, could you, please, elaborate?

Comment: Just change your loop to _For Each btn In me.Controls.OfType(of Button)()_ and use directly _btn_ without checking the Typename because is guaranteed to be a Button

Comment: Cast the control to button `AddHandler CType(control, Button).MouseEnter, AddressOf control.DynamicButton_MouseEnter`

Comment: Says 'Public member 'DynamicButton_MouseEnter' on type 'Button' not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try fetching only the Buttons on the form.
Should cause the control to be of the correct type for attaching a handler.

```
   Private Sub AddButtonEvents()

        For Each control In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button)
            AddHandler control.MouseEnter, AddressOf DynamicButton_MouseEnter
            AddHandler control.MouseLeave, AddressOf DynamicButton_MouseLeave
        Next

    End Sub
```

Or you can loop as you already are doing, and cast as follows

```
    Private Sub AddControlHandlers()

        For Each control In Me.Controls

            If TypeName(control) = "Button" Then

                AddHandler DirectCast(control, Button).MouseEnter, AddressOf DynamicButton_MouseEnter
                AddHandler DirectCast(control, Button).MouseLeave, AddressOf DynamicButton_MouseLeave

            End If

        Next

    End Sub
```

Comment: I understand the answer, however it's not really suitable for me because I am looping through all controls and doing different things to different types of controls. That's why I have the IF statement like ``If TypeName(control) = "Button" Then`` so that I can deduce teh following code to apply to buttons, but I also have different things for ComboBoxes liek ``Elseif TypeName(control) = "ComboBox" then``

Comment: The code in the answer returns the same error where it says that Mouseenter is not an event of object

Comment: Your addressof should refer to "DynamicButton_MouseEnter" and not "control.DynamicButton_MouseEnter", as DynamicButton_MouseEnter is your method and not an event on the control.